# Como ocultar una tabla con jquery con asp.net

Tags: html, jquery

De antemano gracias.

Estoy haciendo  que se oculte una tabla con jquery pero al momento de darle click al boton me muestra la tabla muy rápido y yo lo que quiero es que se quede estática.Osea que no desaparezca a los segundos.

Mi código esta de la siguiente manera:
Como les menciono, estoy en un div donde mando 3 paramitos dependiendo de eso hace una búsqueda, una vez que hace la búsqueda debe mandar solo el filtrado de resultados . Para esto en el momento de poner parámetros no debe verse la tabla la quito con un .hide pero cuando le doy buscar el resultado obvio es la tabla pero me abre y me cierra demasiado rápido no me deja ni consultar bien los datos, alguna idea de mi error ? Espero puedan apoyarme.Es una vista en visual studio trabajado con asp.net

```html
@model IEnumerable<InvesdocServicio.ServiceReferenceInvesdoc.CGuia>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "plistObtenerGuias";
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
   
    @using (Html.BeginForm("plistObtenerDatosGuias", "Invesdoc", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="container-full " style="position:center;">
            <div id="pnlConsultas" class="form-group panel panel-primary margin-bottom-40" style="background: #2C5C82">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #347AB736;">Consulta de documentación </div>
                <div class="panel-body margin-bottom-50">
                    <div class="row" style="justify-content: center; align-items: center; ">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
                            <label>Master</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("lsrMaster", "", new { @class = "form-control", style = "background-color:#00000033; color: white;" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>House</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("lsrHouse", "", new { @class = "form-control", style = "background-color:#00000033; color: white;" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>Registro</label>
                            @Html.TextBox("lsrRegistro", "", new { @class = "form-control", style = "background-color:#00000033; color: white;" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="row text-center" style="padding: 3.5% 1% 1% 1%; position:center; text-align: center;">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnConsultar" id="btnConsultar" value="Buscar" style=" background-color: #00000033; width:110%; color:white; font-size:14px;" formaction="/Invesdoc/plistObtenerGuias" />
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="row text-center" style="padding: 3.5% 2% 1% 2%; position:center; text-align: center;">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnLimpiar" id="btnLimpiar" value="Limpiar" style=" background-color: #00000033; width:110%; color:white; font-size:14px;" />
                    </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gdvConsulta" class="active" @*style="display:none;"*@>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" class="table table-striped" border="1" id="gdvResultadosConsulta" style="font-size: 10px; border-collapse: collapse; background: #2C5C82; color: white; width:188%;">
            <tr>
                <th> Número de Expediente </th>
                <th> Tipo de Expediente </th>
                <th> Master </th>
                <th> House </th>
                <th> Registro </th>
                <th> Documento</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="color:white;">
                    <td>@item.lsrFst136_IdExpediente</td>
                    <td>@item.lsrFst136_NameTipoExpediente</td>
                    <td>@item.lsrFst136_GMaster</td>
                    <td>@item.lsrFst136_GHouse</td>
                    <td>@item.lsrFst136_Registro</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px; background-color:transparent; text-align:center;">
                       
                        <a href="/Invesdoc/plistObtenerDocumento/@item.lsrFst136_IdExpediente" id="gDescargar" style="font-size:16px; color:white;"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       
        $(function () {

            $("#btnConsultar").click(function () {
                $("#gdvConsulta").show();
            });

            $("#btnLimpiar").click(function () {
                $("#gdvConsulta").hide();

            });


            //$("#gdvConsulta").hide();
            //$("#btnConsultar").click(function (e) {

            //    var container = $("#gdvConsulta");

            //    if (container.css('display') == 'none') {
            //        $("#gdvConsulta").show();
            //        $(".gdvConsulta").show("slow");
                    
            //    }
               
            //});
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Les pongo mis dos controladores de estas partes , uno es para la parte del formulario y otra para visualizar la tabla

```
 public ActionResult plistObtenerDatosGuias(string lsrMaster, string lsrHouse, string lsrRegistro)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ServiceReferenceInvesdoc.ServiceClient gconexionServicioInvesDoc = new ServiceReferenceInvesdoc.ServiceClient())
                {
                    List<CGuia> listaObtenerInvesDoc = gconexionServicioInvesDoc.plistObtenerTablaGuias(lsrMaster, lsrHouse, lsrRegistro).ToList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listaObtenerInvesDoc.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Session["lsrIdExpediente"] = listaObtenerInvesDoc[i].lsrFst136_IdExpediente;
                    }
                    return View("plistObtenerGuias",listaObtenerInvesDoc);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["mensaje"] = ex.Message;
                return View("plistObtenerDatosGuias");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult plistObtenerGuias(string lsrMaster, string lsrHouse, string lsrRegistro)
        {
            try
            {
                CGuia p = new CGuia();
                using (ServiceReferenceInvesdoc.ServiceClient gconexionServicioInvesDoc = new ServiceReferenceInvesdoc.ServiceClient())
                {
                    List<CGuia> listaObtenerInvesDoc = gconexionServicioInvesDoc.plistObtenerTablaGuias(lsrMaster, lsrHouse, lsrRegistro).ToList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listaObtenerInvesDoc.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Session["lsrIdExpediente"] = listaObtenerInvesDoc[i].lsrFst136_IdExpediente;
                    }
                    return View(listaObtenerInvesDoc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["mensaje"] = ex.Message;

            }
            return View("plistObtenerGuiasPost");
        }
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que pides. He intentado reproducir tu escenario en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/ywLe06p4/1/) pero no se ver a lo que te refieres.

Comment: Una disculpa supongo que poner todo el código me mandara error

Comment: ya arregle la pregunta

Comment: He puesto tu código en un snippet, y sin tener en cuenta las variables no resueltas, sigo sin poder reproducir tu error o bien no entiendo el problema.  Ejecútalo en pantalla completa a ver si tu error te pasa aqui o no.  Por que si no te pasa aquí es probable que el error suceda cuando se resuelvan las variables y no tal como está ahora.

Comment: supongo que no agarrara porque lo ocupo en una vista que trae un model

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que presionas el botón btnConsultar, se muestra la tabla pero acto seguido se realiza un submit y se recarga la página volviendo a su estado original que es con la tabla oculta.

Todo ese código javascript que tienes debes borrarlo, porque no tiene sentido. Y en donde comienza la tabla poner:

```
@if(Model!=null && Model.Count()>0){

<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gdvConsulta" class="active" @*style="display:none;"*@>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" class="table table-striped" 

<-- El resto de tu código -->
    </form>
}
```

Comment: me cumple lo de ver la tabla al poner darle click al boton y ver los resultados, pero 
 no me oculta la tabla al principio y si lo volteo me la oculta siempre

Comment: @Jaz Estuve revisando y veo cosas raras en tu código. Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el código del controller Invesdoc y los actions plistObtenerDatosGuias y plistObtenerGuias

Comment: agregue la parte del controlador

Comment: @Jaz Tienes al menos 3 vistas plistObtenerGuias y plistObtenerDatosGuias, plistObtenerGuiasPost, verificaste que este cambio estuviera en todas ??(si es que correspondiera, obviamente)

Comment: no, me equivoque en mandar una por lo que noto solo ocupo la primera vista obtenerGuias no ocupo ninguna otra